# Install Linux from dvd to dead windows 7 machine

Tags: system-installation

My sister in law (says she apparently) formatted (ayuh) over her windows 7 hard drive, and I would like to help her make her new "brick" into a useful brick. I am getting everything I need ready to take with me when I go to her house.

Of course step one would be to try to locate a recovery dvd, but it may very well have come without, or it may be AWOL. I don't know from here how much of the necessary licenses and paperwork they have on hand, though they may be. Without the DVD, I don't know my options well, anyway. So I want to be prepared to install Linux...

I am working from a Mac on this end, if possible. If necessary, I can get a windows system, but not windows 7.

Now I think I understand how to create a 'nix liveDVD (download, write dvd) and then I believe if I just pop it in the drive, it should boot up. But from there, how do I actually install Linux onto her hard drive so the dvd is no longer necessary.

Also, if there were to be any data recovery possible, how would I go about approaching that?

Lastly, which distro would be the most recommended for a former windows user with lower intermediate (her) to intermediate skills (me)? As far as I know the computer is mostly used for personal use: internet browsing, watching movies and photos, skype, email, and similar social uses, non advanced document and media creation and editing. No games. No for business use.

Answer (score 2):

If your sister really just formatted the computer, her files are quite easy to recover because only the root of the directory structures is misssing.

**The most important thing is to immediately make an image of the harddisk to an external harddrive. DON'T repair the harddisk directly.**

You can do this easily with any Linux Live CD and and copy all data off the harddisk to an image file using the command `dd`. After that, the original harddisk is best disconnected. You then recover the data from the image file, for example using the incredibly useful `testdisk` program from linux.

Believe me, even if the user says that the files are backed up and/or not important, the backup is not complete and there is important data which could be salvaged. If you install something on the disk, everything will be lost and you are responsible. Don't do it, it's the way to the dark side ;)

Comment: I would give you credit for providing a correct answer, except it answers my question a bit indirectly, and I have no way to know if the answer is correct, because, get this, it turns out, AS I HAD TOLD HER WOULD BE THE CASE, she did not actually delete the hard-drive, and windows 7 booted just fine (after I booted up from my linux live CD, inspected the drive, then restarted.) There was some minor malware to take care of, only. lesson: second guessing is good.

Comment: @asllearner you can still upvote an answer (and give credit for the effort), even if you don't accept it (because it is not the answer that solved your issue).

Comment: There were several questions in your post, and I tried to answer the most important part, data recovery from a bricked computer. What were you missing or in which sense did you feel my answer was indirect?

Comment: Your answer focused on data recovery, but the primary question was how to install linux (see the title). I trust your advice, but I never got to test itin this situation. It was moot. I just don't know if it counts via stackexchange to credit an answer that while correct is partial or that might not be considered by others reading the title, as anthon put it, an "answer that solved [the] issue." Of course, I did gratefully learn something from your answer, and thus  inclined to credit it.